# How do I repair water-damaged hardwood floors?

Tags: repair, flooring, hardwood-floor, water-damage

We moved a pot plant that was sitting on top of the wood floor. We discovered there's a wet spot about 2 inches wide where a couple of seams meet.

The wet spot has probably been there for months.

What measures does one take to repair the wood floor?

Comment: nailed/stapled down or floated?

Comment: i think nailed.

Comment: what is wrong other than the wet spotting?  Is any of the wood damaged/warped/buckling/rotted?

Comment: Just some changes in the color of the wood. It's still wet. Should i wait for it to drive to figure out what to do?

Comment: Photos from like 45 degrees angle would be useful to estimate the damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem in a home I used to own - we pulled up the carpets and found that there were spots where the floor was black underneath.

We sanded the floors to remove the varnish, and then used bleach to fix the discoloration in the hardwood floor.  It turned out really well.

Here are more detailed instructions: http://www.oldhouseweb.com/how-to-advice/how-to-bleach-stains-on-wood-floors.shtml

Do not breathe in the bleach fumes!

P.S.  Let the wood dry before starting this.